# How do I delete a remote branch in Git?

Tags: git

I created a branch `notmaster` to commit as well as push some changes. When I was finished with that branch, I merged the changes back into `master`, pushed them out, and then deleted the local `notmaster`.

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/notmaster
```

Is there anyway to delete the remote `notmaster`?

---

A little more clarity, with the [solution from Ionut](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4159972/478288):

The usual method failed for me:

```
$ git push origin :notmaster
error: dst refspec notmaster matches more than one.
```

That's because I had a tag with the same name as the branch. This was a poor choice on my behalf and caused the ambiguity. So in that case:

```
$ git push origin :refs/heads/notmaster
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`git push origin :notmaster`, which basically means "push nothing to the notmaster remote".

Comment: error: dst refspec notmaster matches more than one.

Comment: That's a first. I haven't seen that error before.

Comment: Ah, your second suggestion worked! I have a tag with the same label as that branch (notmaster). Could that cause the error?

Comment: Oh, yes, that's the cause. I believe you could have deleted it using `git push origin :refs/heads/notmaster`. Not sure though.

Comment: @chrisaycock: That's exactly what caused it. Generally you should avoid duplicating names like that, since some commands work with both tags and branches and become ambiguous.

Comment: @chrisaycock: And in fact, you *need* to do what Ionut suggests (disambiguate to refs/heads/notmaster) because with the `git branch -d -r` command, you've only deleted the local remote tracking branch, not the actual branch on the remote. If you don't delete it on the remote, it'll just show up the next time you fetch.

Comment: @Jefromi is right, I've just re-read what the manual says.

Answer (score 61):

I had the same issue. I had both a branch and a tag named 3.2.
That's why it says there's more than one match:

```
git error: dst refspec 3.2 matches more than one.
```

Here's how to delete the branch:

```
git push origin :heads/3.2
```

And here's how to delete the tag:

```
git push origin :tags/3.2
```

Answer (score 17):

```
git push origin --delete notmaster
```

If you're using Git 1.7.0 or later, this will do the trick. Prior to Git 1.7.0, you needed to use the less intuitive (but equally effective) syntax:

```
git push origin :notmaster
```

The older syntax still works in newer versions of Git, but the newer syntax seems more humane and easier to remember. If I want to *delete* a branch, typing `--delete` seems like the natural thing to do.

From the [1.7.0 release notes](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/RelNotes-1.7.0.txt):

> "git push" learned "git push origin --delete branch", a syntactic sugar for "git push origin :branch".

Answer (score 7):

This happened because the name of the branch and tag is same.

To delete the branch from remote use

`git push origin :refs/heads/branchname`

To delete the tag from remote use

`git push origin :refs/tags/tagname`

To delete from local you can use the following.

`git branch -d branchname`

`git tag -d tagname`

Answer (score 1):

**Delete local branch:**

```
git branch -d {branch name} //All changes must be committed first.
git branch -D {branch name} //Does not require commit.
```

**Delete Gitorious Branch:**

```
Delete the local branch first.
git push {gitorious push url} :{branch name}
```

Comment: The second of your two answers is what the OP was looking for, though it's by no means specific to gitorious, and you don't need a URL - just a remote name, which the OP gave. `git push origin :notmaster`, or in this case, `git push origin :refs/heads/notmaster` would be a clearer answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps can do the trick as well:

```
$ git fetch --prune --tags
$ git push origin :refs/tags/{same-branch-tag-name}
$ git push origin :{same-branch-tag-name}
$ git push --tags
```