# How do I delete a branch from GitHub?

Tags: github

I saw previous posts asking about this, but none that solved it for me.  I don't use Git through the command line, I use it as it's integrated into Xcode.  I created a branch and pushed it to GitHub, and now I want to delete it.  I deleted it in Xcode, but it's still on GitHub.  The GitHub directions say to just go to Admin and delete the repo, but there it says it'll delete the whole project, not just the branch.  So what am I missing?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159950/how-do-i-delete-remote-branch-in-git

Comment: What's different about your situation from the other question?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You want to delete a *branch* on github? Just do

```
$ git push origin :branch-name
```

where you have to substitute `origin` with the name of the remote repository and `branch-name` with the name of the branch you want to delete at github.

**Edit:** Note the colon in front of the branch name, it is important.

**Edit 2:** To be more verbose:

```
$ cd /path/to/local/git/checkout
$ git remote -v show
```

Pick the remote name from the first column which corresponds to
the github URL where you want to delete the branch. I call it
`origin` here. `branch-name` is the name of the branch you want to delete. Delete it using:

```
$ git push origin :branch-name
```

**Edit 3:** If you want to learn about git, I can recommend the free book by Scott Chacon. The relevant section is [here](http://progit.org/book/ch3-5.html#deleting_remote_branches).