# How to remove a git remote branch naming the same with a tag?

Tags: git

I make a mistake to push a tag name v2.3, I already have the branch name v2.3.
When I try to remove the branch v2.3:

```
git push origin :v2.3
```

It said,

```
qty:ibt-common qrtt1$ git push origin :v2.3 :v2.3_working
error: dst refspec v2.3 matches more than one.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:mygit/common.git'
```

Is it possible to remove the branch when naming conflict ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could disambiguate the refspec like this:

```
git push origin :refs/heads/branchname
```

More information [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159950/how-do-i-delete-a-remote-branch-in-git).